# Problems in the io module for python

Tags: python

I am currently running python version 2.5.2 in my system and I am having some problems regarding io module. The system shows "No module named io" found. I wanted to ask if there is anyway I can get io module in my system. I couldn't install it using pip or easy_install. Any alternatives. I can't upgrade my python version though.

Here is some traceback of the code

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback
      raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e))) 
Local vars

    'upload_ssv'
     e ImportError('No module named io',)
     mod_name 'mysite.lists.views'
     self<RegexURLPattern submit-csv ^upload_ssv/$>
```

Here is some snippets from mysite.lists.views file

```
import cStringIO as StringIO
import datetime, csv
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from dateutil.parser import parse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from mysite.wire.models import Screening, Company, Union, Funder
from mysite.users.models import UserProfile
from mysite.wire.forms import EmailForm, CSVForm
from mysite.lists.models import List, ListEntry
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from forms import SSVForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def upload_ssv(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SSVForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        for result in form.parsed_data:
            # TODO: Screening model - confirmation ID = ID of a screening
            print result
else:
    form = SSVForm()
return render_to_response('lists/upload_ssv.html', locals(), RequestContext(request))
```

The snippet from urls.py file

```
url(r'^upload-ssv/$', 'sureaudio.lists.views.upload_ssv', name='upload-ssv'),
```

Comment: What's wrong with the default file object?

Comment: Please remember to accept answers to your questions by clicking the check mark next to the best one. You haven't accepted an answer to any of your last __ten__ questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do what you want with the [builtin `file` object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) (or simply the [builtin `open` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)), the only analogs to functionality in the `io` library available in Python 2 are the [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/module-StringIO.html) and [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/module-cStringIO.html) modules.

If you give us more information about what features of `io` you need, or what package you're trying to use that requires it, we can recommend alternatives.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to debug the code written by another person. I can see that this person has imported cStringIO module itself rather than the io module. I can see that io module is not imported from anywhere else. But still, I am getting Error was: No module named io. It's really strange

Comment: Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Could not import mysite.lists.views. Error was: No module named io. I just get this error. Actually this views file is importing the cStringIO module.

Comment: it just does `import cStringIO` or it does `from io import cStringIO`? If it's the second version, change it to the first. To post code or tracebacks, please edit it into your original question.

Comment: Of course it does import cStringIO as StringIO. I have posted some traceback of the error in my original post

Comment: Need to see the actual import code. Show the chunk of the view where this happens!

Comment: Does `forms` do an `import io` in `SSVForm`? That appears to be where the error originates. You either didn't post the complete traceback or it's just odd because of Django, so I can't tell otherwise what might be the problem.

Comment: @agf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2516/discussion-between-rajan-sthapit-and-agf)

Answer (score -2):

Update your Python.

If you don't have the resources to build it from source yourself, then go to Activestate here http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads and download the AS version for Linux. It can be installed to your home directory and is entirely separate from the Python that is installed with the system. If you have a Mac, then get the Activestate disk image.

If you are on Windows and don't have Administrator Rights then get Portable Python http://www.portablepython.com/ or Moveable Python http://code.google.com/p/movable-python/

In fact, many Python libraries can be installed simply by copying their files to your Python's site-packages library folder. Similarly, if you have access to the same version of Python as you have installed, you could repair your install by copying over the io module (it is a single file named io.py) or you could even install io.py to your current working directory and it would function the same way.

Take the time to get to know how Python modules are structured, how the PYTHONPATH environment variable works, and sys.path (import sys; print sys.path) and the layout of Python's directories.

If you are serious about Python then you will never use an OS installed version of Python again unless you are doing system admin scripts. Real app development demands that you take charge of your development environment.

Comment: He specifically said he can't upgrade Python. I'm assuming this isn't a lack of knowhow but an outside restriction.

Comment: I assumed that this *IS* an outside restriction. It is quite common for IT people to ban installation of stuff on a Windows PC, or a UNIX server because it messes up their standard build to change things. That's why I explained how to upgrade without changing the standard build, but by adding beside it. You can have your cake and eat it too. Leave the standard system Python alone so that nothing breaks, and install your own Python on the side as part of the application that you are building.